# Dataframes are slow to parse through small amount of data

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 classes doing a similar task in Apache Spark but the one using data frame is many times slower than the "regular" one using RDD. (30x)

I would like to use data frame since it will eliminate a lot of code and classes we have but obviously I can't have it be that much slower.

The data set is nothing big. We have 30 some files with json data in each about events triggered from activities in another piece of software. There are between 0 to 100 events in each file.

A data set with 82 events will take about 5 minutes to be processed with data frames.

Sample code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
  SparkConf sc = new SparkConf().setAppName("POC");
  JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
  SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);

  conf = new ConfImpl();

  HashSet<String> siteSet = new HashSet<>();

  // last month
  Date yesterday = monthDate(DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -1)); // method that returns the date on the first of the month
  Date startTime = startofYear(new Date(yesterday.getTime())); // method that returns the date on the first of the year

  // list all the sites with a metric file
  JavaPairRDD<String, String> allMetricFiles = jsc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs:///somePath/*/poc.json");
  for ( Tuple2<String, String> each : allMetricFiles.toArray() ) {
    logger.info("Reading from " + each._1);
    DataFrame metric = sqlContext.read().format("json").load(each._1).cache();
    metric.count();
    boolean siteNameDisplayed = false;
    boolean dateDisplayed = false;

    do {
      Date endTime = DateUtils.addMonths(startTime, 1);
      HashSet<Row> totalUsersForThisMonth = new HashSet<>();
      for (String dataPoint : Conf.DataPoints) { // This is a String[] with 4 elements for this specific case
        try {
          if (siteNameDisplayed == false) {
            String siteName = parseSiteFromPath(each._1); // method returning a parsed String
            logger.info("Data for site: " + siteName);
            siteSet.add(siteName);
            siteNameDisplayed = true;
          }
          if ( dateDisplayed == false ) {
            logger.info("Month: " + formatDate(startTime)); // SimpleFormatDate("yyyy-MM-dd")
            dateDisplayed = true;
          }
          DataFrame lastMonth = metric.filter("event.eventId=\"" + dataPoint + "\"").filter("creationDate >= " + startTime.getTime()).filter("creationDate < " + endTime.getTime()).select("event.data.UserId").distinct();
          logger.info("Distinct for last month for " + dataPoint + ": " + lastMonth.count());
          totalUsersForThisMonth.addAll(lastMonth.collectAsList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // data does not fit the expected model so there is nothing to print
        }
      }
      logger.info("Total Unique for the month: " + totalStudentForThisMonth.size());
      startTime = DateUtils.addMonths(startTime, 1);
      dateDisplayed = false;
    } while ( startTime.getTime() < commonTmsMetric.monthDate(yesterday).getTime());

    // reset startTime for the next site
    startTime = commonTmsMetric.StartofYear(new Date(yesterday.getTime()));
  }
}
```

There are a few things that are not efficient in this code but when I look at the logs it only adds a few seconds to the whole processing.

I must be missing something big.

I have ran this with 2 executors and 1 executor and the difference is 20 seconds on 5 minutes.

This is running with Java 1.7 and Spark 1.4.1 on Hadoop 2.5.0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there a few things, but its hard to say without seeing the breakdown of the different tasks & their time. The short version is you are doing way to much work in the driver and not taking advantage of Spark's distributed capabilities.

For example, you are collecting all of the data back to the driver program (toArray() and your for loop). Instead you should just point Spark SQL at the files in needs to load.

For the operators, it seems like your doing many aggregations in the driver, instead you could use the driver to generate the aggregations and have Spark SQL execute them.

Another big difference between your in-house code and the DataFrame code is going to be Schema inference. Since you've already created classes to represent your data, it seems likely that you know the schema of your JSON data. You can likely speed up your code by adding the schema information at read time so Spark SQL can skip inference.

I'd suggest re-visiting this approach and trying to build something using Spark SQL's distributed operators.

Comment: There are many things to address and I will start working on them to see how it improves the performance. How can I measure the cost of the inference I would prefer the data frame takes care of. One of the goal to switch to data frame was to remove the many classes that defines the json.